# Extending the "Dynamic Web Project" Wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

Is it possible to extend the 'dynamic web project' wizard of Eclipse?

I would like to create my own wizard that generates a dynamic web project based on my own templates. I was able to create my own java project wizard and then apply the web facets/natures but I would like to reuse the UI of the 'dynamic web project' wizard.

Answer (score 1):

If the *dynamic web projects wizard* is not designed for extension, you would need to create a copy for your extensions.

See also an article about [extension points](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Check this out: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-BuildingProjectFacets/tutorial.html